# To define the no of connections from Source to destination Ip

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame with source and destination Ip as columns and want to see how many connections were established between them. In a nutshell, I want to have a column name as "count", that tells me how many times source Ip tried connecting to destination Ip.

Below is a snapshot of the data frame:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWCFW.png)

```
The desired O/p will be like:
Source Ip      Destination Ip     Count
175.45.176.0   149.171.126.16     1
175.45.176.1   149.171.126.18     1
175.45.176.2   149.171.126.16     1
'
'
'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi ways to do that.

1. Groupby then count

```py
df_ = df.groupby(['SourceIP', 'DestinationIP'])['DestinationIP'].count().reset_index(name="count")
```

```
print(df_)

       SourceIP   DestinationIP  count
0  175.45.176.0  149.171.126.16      1
1  175.45.176.2  149.171.126.10      1
2  175.45.176.2  149.171.126.16      2
3  175.45.176.3  149.171.126.18      1
```

2. Groupby then agg(count)

```py
df_ = df.groupby(['SourceIP', 'DestinationIP']).agg(count=pd.NamedAgg(column="DestinationIP", aggfunc="count")).reset_index()
```

```
print(df_)

       SourceIP   DestinationIP  count
0  175.45.176.0  149.171.126.16      1
1  175.45.176.2  149.171.126.10      1
2  175.45.176.2  149.171.126.16      2
3  175.45.176.3  149.171.126.18      1
```

3. `value_counts()` on columns

```py
df_ = df.value_counts(['SourceIP', 'DestinationIP']).reset_index(name='count')
```

```
print(df_)

       SourceIP   DestinationIP  count
0  175.45.176.2  149.171.126.16      2
1  175.45.176.0  149.171.126.16      1
2  175.45.176.2  149.171.126.10      1
3  175.45.176.3  149.171.126.18      1
```